# Is std::wcout interpreting strings as UCS-2 on Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, unicode

Is `std::wcout` interpreting strings as UCS-2 on Windows? If I compile and run the following in MSVC

```
int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    const wchar_t str[] = L"Hello, World! こんにちは世界! ";
    std::wcout << str;
}
```

I get the output: `Hello, World! こんにちは世界! ��`

But if I call `WriteConsoleW` I get `Hello, World! こんにちは世界!`

So it seems like with `std::wcout` only code points in the BMP are supported, even though the Windows console clearly supports UTF-16. I cannot find this mentioned anywhere. Everyone just says set `_O_U16TEXT` and you are good to Unicode.

Comment: "*Is `std::wcout` interpreting strings as UCS-2 on Windows?*" - no, it doesn't interpret them at all, it just writes the `wchar_t` characters as-is to the console, and it is the console's responsibility to interpret and display them accordingly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I told you that `WriteConsoleW` supports all UTF-16 but `wcout` only seems to support BMP code points. So clearly there's something happening in-between the call to `operator<<` and the terminal.

Comment: check your STL's actual implementation to see what `wcout` is actually doing, but I would be surprised if the default implementation on Windows doesn't ultimately call `WriteConsoleW()` or equivalent when its buffer is flushed to stdout.